# Repeating Text Inside a For Loop in Lua

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, text, lua

I was wondering if it is possible to use a for loop to add text several times in the same line.

Ex:

```
while true do
    for i = 1,3,1 do
        local text = ("pending" + ("." * i))
        print(text)
        wait(1)
    end
end
```

I know this example does not work, however I was just wondering if another way, without checking the variable, i, every time.

Comment: Do you just want a way to make a string with repeated dots, or do you want the interpreter to be able to remember how many dots to use without you having to reference `i`?

Comment: I want to make a string with repeated dots

Comment: what I meant by not having to check the variable, is that I don't want to write an if statement, checking the value of i and then adding the amount of dots manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Most importantly, `text` should not be local in the for loop, if its
  value is to be preseve between the iterations.
- If the dots are not to
  be reset every three seconds, `text` should not be local in the while
  loop, either.
- You have to write the `wait` function yourself. To
  repeat dots, use `string.rep (str, number)`.
- Lua concatenation operator is `..`.

```lua
-- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-03/msg00212.html
function wait (seconds)
    local start = os.time ()
    repeat until os.time () > start + seconds
end

while true do
    local text
    for i = 1, 3 do
        text = 'pending ' .. string.rep ('.', i)
        print (text)
        wait (1)
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks, although all I needed was the string.rep()